# What happens to a cache line that maps to a memory area that's subsequently deallocated?

Tags: caching

Does the line get invalidated at deallocation, or just stay in the cache until it gets evicted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cache line is not affected by the de-allocation, i.e., software doesn't inform the cache to invalidate the line.